# Ip address server not found with the domain from Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I registered a domain from Route 53 in AWS, and try to link it to a EC2 instance created from AWS. More precisely, I set up an WordPress instance in EC2, and I would like to use my own domain registered from Route 53 to get access to the instance rather than the ip address. However, I got "ip address server not found" error when I type the domain in different browers on different devices. But I can get access to the instance when I type the ip address directly. Here is what I have done:

1. Set up the WordPress instance in EC2, and allocate elastic IP address
2. Test whether I can type the IP address obained above to access the WordPress instance. And the answer is Yes
3. I create the host zone in Route 53 and add a record which maps to the IP address obtained above. I also make sure the same name is used in the instance and the host zone as suggested.

Here is the set up of my Route 53. How should I solve this problem?

[Set up of my Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXbU1.jpg)

Comment: Is that a public hosted zone? Is the domain registered with AWS? `dig mingjiaxie.com +trace` does not lead to the mentioned nameservers and therefore does not lead to the IP.

Comment: Thank you @luk2302. However, I just check the type of my host zone, and it is indeed public. I actually delete the old host zone, and create a new one which is public. And it still does not help.